# Discord.js wait between sending several files

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm new to javascript, I made a code that would dump several files on a channel. However, I want that for each file sent, the bot waits about 5-10 seconds and then sends the next file, and so on.
With the code I made, the bot waits 5 seconds, but then posts all the files one after another, instead of waiting 5 seconds between each file sent. I hope someone can help, here's the code:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');

module.exports = {
    name: 'dump',
    description: "dumps files from a folder",
    execute(message, args, command){
        if (command.startsWith("dump")){
            const Dump = fs.readdirSync('./dump/');
            for(const file of Dump){
            const File = String("./dump/" + file);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                message.channel.send({
                    files: [File]
                    });
            }, 5000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Figured it out, posted correction on answer.

Comment: What you're looking for in `setInterval` not `setTimeout`.   `setTimeout` will wait the given amount of time before running a function whereas  `setInterval` will run the function every given amount of time. Simpl change  `setTimeout to `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Changing it to setInterval made the bot wait the 5 seconds then post the files over and over, not respecting the 5 seconds wait either

Comment: Add the logic for sending the files into its own function and then call that function inside `setInterval` so something like `setInterval(sendFileFunction, 5000);`

Comment: Still run into the same issue of the bot waiting 5 seconds then posts all the files at the same time (sorry I don't know how to paste the new code here)

Comment: Ohh sorry @Acies Gecko you mean you want the files to be posted one then five seconds then one again then five seconds, not every five seconds. My bad

Comment: Yes, I want to send several files, but one every 5-10 seconds so it doesn't spam the server

Comment: Fixed it with an async function. I didn't think of that, thanks for your help and quick replies though.

Answer (score 1):

Made it to work with a simple async function. Probably needs improvement because I just recently started coding, although it works.

Working result:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');

module.exports = {
    name: 'dump',
    description: "dumps files from a folder",
    execute(message, args, command){
        if (command.startsWith("dump")){
            async function dumpFiles() {
                const Dump = fs.readdirSync('./dump/');
                let wait = async (ms) => await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r,ms));
                for(const file of Dump){
                const File = String("./dump/" + file);
                message.channel.send({files: [File]});
                await wait(5000)
                }
            }
            dumpFiles()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

due to the nature of Javascript the code is asynchronous, so in order to wait 5 seconds between each sending, you have to force the code to wait until a send is done.

For example:

```
const array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

for(const value of array){
   const time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
   setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log(`${value} took: ${time}ms`);
     }, time); 
}
```

If you run that piece of script, you will see that the values are not printed out in order, which means that the time used in the **setTimeout** is not making the things wait.

So a fix could be to make all the code synchronous, but that will include extra work. There is already a function build-in Javascript to do things with intervals.

You can try out the function **setInterval()**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: SetInterval didn't work either, but the async did.

Comment: @AciesGecko great job. Please post the answer as it could be useful to others.